# Excel running total / window function

Tags: excel, t-sql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

Say we have some data as followed

```
Datetime             Type  Sale
25/07/2016 03:21      A     12
25/07/2016 04:00      B     23
25/07/2016 15:20      B     5
26/07/2016 05:15      A     15
26/07/2016 10:20      A     3
26/07/2016 16:10      B     20
27/07/2016 10:10      B     5

.......
```

Question is "Find the 36-hour frame where we have the largest total sales of type A product" using **Excel**.

From what I understand and if I try to approach it, the 36-hour frame would mean for each entry, we'll look at the frame from that point onwards. For example, take the first entry, the frame starting with it would be 25/07/2016 03:21 -> 26/07/2016 15:21, 1.5 day later, meaning the sum for this frame is 12+15+3. Taking anything later or sooner than the entry being considered would reduce the sum, wouldn't it ? By taking each entry as starting point, your sum 'spans the furthest'.

1. It looks like a windowed sum in SQL to me. How would you find a solution only using Excel ?
2. It would be nice if you can provide a solution in SQL as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please paste the expected output..For Excel running total ,check this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-a-running-total-170fa72a-a0f4-4476-9708-5a9f993668e9

Comment: I don't have the original input nor output. It was a test question. What would your approach be, independent of the real input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a lot more detail on how your 36 hour window works; is it just any arbitrary 26 hour window or are they set intervals with defined start and end points?  If it is the latter you can only do this with an additional Datetime Periods table for you to calculate the sums on.

For the former however, you can look at the 36 hour period before and after each sale and then find the max of those values.  The easiest way to do this is use a `Table` in excel and the following `SUMIFS` formulas, which look for all sales of the same type as in the row that have a Datetime value 36 hours (1.5 days) either before or after the Datetime value in the given row:

Start by selecting you data and then Inserting a Table:

[image]

Then add two columns and enter the following formulas:

**Prev 36 Hours:**
=SUMIFS([Sale],[Type],[@Type],[Datetime],">"&[@Datetime]-1.5,[Datetime],"<="&[@Datetime])

**Next 36 Hours:**
=SUMIFS([Sale],[Type],[@Type],[Datetime],"<"&[@Datetime]+1.5,[Datetime],">="&[@Datetime])

[image]

To do this in SQL using 36 hour periods from the Datetime value you can use the following.  I have included both the previous and following 36 hour periods as by only looking in one direction will miss out sales at either the start or the end of the dataset.  Windowed Functions do not let you specify data driven windows so you need to use either joins or sub-selects to achieve what you are after:

```
declare @data table(dt Datetime, Type nvarchar(50), Sale int)
insert into @data
values
 ('2016/07/25 03:21','A',12)
,('2016/07/25 04:00','B',23)
,('2016/07/25 15:20','B',5)
,('2016/07/26 05:15','A',15)
,('2016/07/26 10:20','A',3)
,('2016/07/26 16:10','B',20)
,('2016/07/27 10:10','B',5)

select a.dt
        ,a.Type
        ,a.Sale
        ,sum(dprev.Sale) as PrevSales
        ,a.NextSales
from(
    -- If you only want the proceeding 36 hour period you can just use this part --
    select d.dt
            ,d.Type
            ,d.Sale
            ,sum(dnext.Sale) as NextSales
    from @data d
        left join @data dnext
            on(d.Type = dnext.Type
                and dnext.dt between d.dt and dateadd(hour,+36,d.dt)
                )
    group by d.dt
            ,d.Type
            ,d.Sale
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
) a
    left join @data dprev
        on(a.Type = dprev.Type
            and dprev.dt between dateadd(hour,-36,a.dt) and a.dt
            )
group by a.dt
        ,a.Type
        ,a.Sale
        ,a.NextSales
order by a.Type
        ,a.dt
```

Comment: That's one major point of the question I suppose. See my updated question.  If you define an arbitrary 36-h you will not have an optimal sum. The 36-h should start at each entry to "span the furthest".

Comment: @Kenny Edited answer to reflect 36 hour period definition.

Answer (score 1):

write in E2 with the formula below
`=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$B$2:$B$8,"=A",$A$2:$A$8,">="&A2,$A$2:$A$8,"<"&A2+1.5)`

[image]